# Flutter Throws An Error While Running An App

Tags: flutter

I am trying out flutter and it throws an error while I try to run the app on my external device.[image]

I don't understand what the error is. Can someone help me figure it out?

Comment: Is your connection working? are you behind a proxy?

Comment: yes it is working...